# Unable to kill port 4200 while having IntelliJ open

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, intellij-idea, port

When I try to run my angular UI with port 4200 with IntelliJ, it said the port is in use.

### What I've tried

- I tried to run npx kill-port 4200, it didn’t work.
- I tried to run taskkill the PID linked to port 4200, then it closed my IntelliJ.
- I tried to restart my computer and open IntelliJ again. It still says the port is in use!
  It is really weird since after I restart my computer the port is somehow still miraculously running!

Is there any way for me to terminate this running port on IntelliJ ? (I am not considering changing to another port)

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Do you at least know what's using port 4200? You have not mentioned it.

Comment: It is the angular UI that I run using `npm start`. I tried to `npm stop` it but it failed.

Comment: IDEA doesn't normally run anything on this port. Please check your setting for the built-in server port in **Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Debugger** - what does it look like? Please could you share a screenshot of this page?